# Webtatic PHP7.1 is missing

Tags: centos, php-7.1

After installing PHP7.1 using this on CentOS7

https://webtatic.com/packages/php71/

Running

```
php -v
```

Results in

> -bash: php: command not found

The install worked but PHP is not there - have I missed a step?

Answer (score 5):

Since you have installed php from webtatic, you'll need to install the cli SAPI.

To do that you need to run:

```
sudo yum install php71w-cli
```

After the installation, try running the below to see if it works:

```
php --version
```

> https://webtatic.com/packages/php71/
>
> Contained in the php71w-cli package, this SAPI allows running scripts from the command-line, and also has a built-in web server for development-use. Located at /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on my computer. For me the command was just renamed to php7 or php71. So if have the same issue please create a symlink.

1. Find out where your php7 file is residing

   $ which php7
   /usr/bin/php7
2. Symlink this file

   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php7 /usr/bin/php
3. Test that this is working

   php -v

Your problem should be solved. Only case might be that you need to change newly created file as executable or change the owner/group.

Please let me know if this was helpful.